# How to create Spring Project using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

The below picture is the structure of my project.

And I'm using this method to initializing Spring context.

```
static ApplicationContext context 
    = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:context-*.xml");
```

When I run main method at Intellij IDEA. Its working fine.

But if I package project to jar by using Maven, And run project by `java -jar wireless-service.jar`

I got this output.

It looks like that Spring didn't found `context-datasource.xml`, `context-mybatis.xml`, etc...

```
Resolved location pattern [classpath*:context-*.xml] to resources []
Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:context-*.xml]
```

So, what is the right config of Spring with Maven?

[image]

---

**EDIT**

And this picture is structure of `wireless-server.jar`

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

I just change the config path to `classpath*:context.xml` and create the `context.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" default-autowire="byName"
   default-lazy-init="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <import resource="context-datasource.xml"></import>
    <import resource="context-mybatis.xml"></import>
    <import resource="context-resource.xml"></import>
    <import resource="context-service.xml"></import>
</beans>
```

Then I run `wireless-server.jar` again.

I got different error info:

```
guration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/root/wireless-server-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/context-mybatis.xml]
```

And Its work well in Intellij IDEA by running main method.

---

**Finally**

I modified `<build>` section in `pom.xml` as this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>${app.main.class}</Main-Class>
                                    <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                                    <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And now all things just work fine!

Comment: can you try changing pattern to `classpath*:/context-*.xml` and then (if doesn't work) `classpath:context-*.xml`

Comment: didn't work of both config. prefix of path must be `classpath*`, if using `classpath`, will get `Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [classpath:/context-*.xml]`. another one is also `Loaded 0 bean definitions`

Comment: Consider [deploying the app as exploded jar](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/06/18/deploying-standalone-java-project/) instead of single (uber) jar

Answer (score 2):

From the [Spring 3.0 Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch05s07.html):

> 5.7.2.3 Other notes relating to wildcards
>
> Please note that "classpath*:" when combined with Ant-style patterns will only work
> reliably with at least one root directory before the pattern starts, unless the actual target files reside in the file system. This means that a pattern like "classpath*:*.xml" will not retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the root of expanded directories. This originates from a limitation in the JDK's ClassLoader.getResources() method which only returns file system locations for a passed-in empty string (indicating potential roots to search).

Comment: I am in junit world, so it is in file system, still this wont work